# U SQL string column size is >128 KB

Tags: u-sql

I have an input file that contains one column which size is more than 128kb. I follow workaround guides to write a custom extractor, extract that as a byte array, and now I am not sure how to proceed with processing of that column. 
What should i do when i extract that as a byte[] ? I try to write a custom outputter also but and then in outputter class to convert that to string but it throws me the same error message

> String size 828267 exceeds the maximum allowed size of 131072

. Can someone explain me steps after extracting that column as byte[], how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

This is limitation of String Data Type. You can vote [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/327234-data-lake/suggestions/13416093-usql-string-data-type-has-a-size-limit-of-128kb) to be considered to improvement :)

There is a workaround which involves converting and handling it as a byte[]. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44631022/value-too-long-failure-when-attempting-to-convert-column-data) post.

Comment: hi @Rui thanks for your comment. I saw this post but i am not sure how to process byte[] type. So when i extract column as a byte[] i convert it in a string so i can clean that field but it throws me an error. In which step I can convert it back to string?

Comment: Hi @DraganB, check [this](https://github.com/Azure/usql/issues/46) post. I think that "kszicsillag" created one custom extractor, based on [this](https://github.com/Azure/usql/blob/mrys-json/Examples/DataFormats/Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats/Json/JsonExtractor.cs), that can help you. I think that you will not be able to work with a string with that size, you have to "clean" it while you're extracting it for example.

Comment: Thanks, I also saw that (so, to be honest, I did a lot of research) :)) 
The thing is my input file is .txt, so I am not working with JSON object or something similar. I created my own extractor, where i need to split a file by rows and columns, and there I read stream as a string (ReadToEnd()) and i think it couldn't process a string that size in c# class also.

Comment: Oh, that's a bigger problem then. I think that in c# the limit is 4Mb. Maybe you will need to redo the way how your files are generated :|

Comment: for now, I removed a column that is causing this issue (Intuition tells me it's not necessary). :))
waiting for business to validate
Thanks anyway